# Why every time in Selenium Webdriver the “ID” of any web element gets changed?

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have written a **script** which sends an **email** using **Selenium Webdriver** (Python bindings). But sometimes, when I run that script the **ID of element gets changed**.

**Error trace-back:**

```
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-
py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in 
check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
elenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such 
element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":":pm"}
```

And sometimes, if I am using valid **XPath**, or **CSS** **Selector**, then the same error is displayed.

Can anyone suggest the best way to make the script work? Also, why is it that every time the **Id** of the element gets changed?

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
usr = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").clear()
usr.send_keys("id@anymail.com")

nextb = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext")
nextb.click()

pwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
pwd.send_keys("**Enter your password**")  

nextpwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/content/span')
nextpwd.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=':hs']/div/div").click()

time.sleep(3)
to = driver.find_element_by_id(":nf")
to.send_keys("XYZ@gmail.com")

sub = driver.find_element_by_id(":my")
sub.send_keys("with attachment")    

descp = driver.find_element_by_id(":nx")
descp.send_keys(" Hi! this second one.")

driver.find_element_by_id(":om").click() #attachmment
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=\"file\"]").send_keys("/home/example.png")
#sead the mail
driver.find_element_by_id(":mo").click()
```

Comment: it recommended that always share your code and html of page which you are using,so that someone can help you

Comment: yae exactly, please share your code and html of the page. Dynamic ids can be easily captured using other locators attributes and by using xpath functions as well. Hence would be great if you can share the html of the page. Thanks !

Comment: Shivangi, I'd advise you to click **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44967183/edit)** and add the `HTML` part that encloses the elements you are trying to locate. Add the script code as well. Else, you're going to get bad, vague answers.

Comment: thanks, all of you for your advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean that Id is dynamic? It means that upon each page load element's id changing fully or partly.

In case there's no static part (each time id is 100% random) - you won't be able to use it as locator and should use other attributes/elements to find required one. Like `//someParentElement/div[@class='someClass']` - meaning that you can find element's parent element, or use additional attributes like class/value/etc.

In case there's static `part` upon each load - you can use css or xPath locator that search for element which contains/starts-with static `part`.

**Search for element where id contains some `part`:**

> `//*[contains(@id,'part')]` - id contains part xpath locator
>
> `[id*=part]` - id contains part css locator

**Search for element where id starts with some `part`:**

> `//*[starts-with(@id,'part')]` - id starts with part xpath locator
>
> `[id^=part]` - id starts with part css locator

Answer (score 0):

```
d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='extension-settings-grid']/div/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div")).click();

//d.findElement(By.className("dx-item-content dx-toolbar-item-content")).click();
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of how this answers the original question.